# Deduce series from the generating function

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

My question is rather simple. I have a recurrence relation. After many transformations, I have arrived at the point where I know the generating function is $$A(x) = \dfrac{2x}{(1-x)^4}$$
Now I want to know the series from which this function is derived, so I can get some sort of a closed formula for the series $a_n$.

Normally, when in this situation, I would perform some transformation so the function has a form which I can recognize, and from which I can find the series. However with this I am rather stuck.

(The function $A(x)$ also has other terms, which I already know the series of. It is this that is being a pain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \binom{n+k}{k}x^k.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, however it is the $2x$ numerator that has been confusing me. In my knowledge, I cannot just separate it as $$2x \cdot \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^4}$$ and multiply the series for both of them

Comment: The $2$ will make it $2$ times the binomial coefficient & the factor of $x$ will shift the index of $k$ by $1$.

Comment: just multiply the entire series by $2x$ and adjust the index to $i = k+1$

Comment: In this case then $n=3$ so the power series will look like $$2x \sum_{k \geq 0} {{k+3} \choose k} x^k = 2 \sum_{k \geq 0} {{k+3} \choose k} x^{k+1} = 2 \sum_{k \geq 0} {{k+2} \choose {k-1}} x^{k}$$, finally giving me the series $$(a_n) = 2 {{k+2} \choose {k-1}}$$. Is this correct?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
a_k= 2 \binom{k+2}{3} = \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{12}.
\end{eqnarray*}